# Anime where the hero teams up with the daughter of an evil goddess and a scientist?

Tags: story-identification, anime

The goddess was the classic long blonde hair scientist guy had like short white hair think the daughter had white hair. Important bit is that her mom abandoned them to be a goddess because he wouldn't devout himself to her 100% because they had a daughter or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: Does he team up with the daughter and a scientist. Or is she the daughter of the scientist as well as the goddess?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.